# Solr: Single document with multi-valued field or multiple flattened documents

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using DIH with TikaProcessor to extract binary data from database and SolrJ API for querying.

We have data structure like below where one order can have multiple attachments. The attachments can contain huge binary data in the range of 100-300 mb.

**Order Table**

orderId  |  details

**Attachments Table**

AttId  |  data  |   orderId

**With this structure what is the best way to create solr documents?**

Option 1:  One solr document for each order with multi-valued field for attachments

Option 2: One document for each attachment - flattened out structure. And use solr grouping/collapsing if we need all documents for an order.

We need highlighting capabilities also.

What would be the performance impact of each options? I am more leaning towards option 2. Any thoughts?